# Maximize a popup window in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

I have a piece of JavaScript code that maximizes browsers window in IE but I doesn't make any changes when I work with Chrome.

This is the code I am talking about.

```
window.moveTo(0, 0);
if (document.all) {
     top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
}
else if (document.layers || document.getElementById) {
     if (top.window.outerHeight < screen.availHeight || top.window.outerWidth < screen.availWidth) {
          top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
          top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
     }
}
```

Does anyone know a good workaround or any other solution to maximize a popup window.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it this way:

```
top.window.moveTo(0,0); 
if (document.all)
{ 
    top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight); 
} 
else if (document.layers || document.getElementById) 
{ 
    if (top.window.outerHeight < screen.availHeight || top.window.outerWidth < screen.availWidth)
    {
        window.resizeTo(top.screen.availWidth, top.screen.availHeight);
    } 
}
```

Note: Browsers will whine about it (and visitors too likely), asking the visitor if he/she wants to allow blocked content, etc. But I guess that's another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Mehmat if you are talking about maximizing window both in IE and Chrome then I suggest you should better use ExtJS or jQuery approach. 
These are cross-browser light weight Javascript libraries and I guess they can help resolve your issue much simpler way.